# After fopen, can I search for a keyword in PHP?

Tags: php, stream, fopen

If I use `fopen` on a file, is there any way to scan through the file to find the number of bytes a certain keyword begins at? If not, how can I do this?

Comment: Oh, hey. Didn't expect to see you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way,

```
$data = file_get_contents("file");
print strpos("$data","myword");
```

Comment: Reading the entire contents of the file into memory could exhaust it.

Comment: "$data" seems redundant to me. Is that to catch null values or something?

Comment: Its not really redundant like you said. $data, like any other variables, can be used later on in the code if required.

Answer (score 0):

The way you phrase this question makes it sound like you're looking for something other than basic string manipulation. If that's what you're saying - nope, string functions are your only option.

Just get the content as you normally would.

```
$content = fread($file_handle, filesize($filename));
$index = strpos($content, 'keyword');
```